# nodejs / express - fresh install fails when attempting to navigate to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just installed node and express on a new dev server...
and I created a test app by running the following command:

```
dev-server15:/var/www# express mytest

   create : mytest
   create : mytest/package.json
   create : mytest/app.js
   create : mytest/public
   create : mytest/public/javascripts
   create : mytest/public/images
   create : mytest/public/stylesheets
   create : mytest/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : mytest/routes
   create : mytest/routes/index.js
   create : mytest/routes/users.js
   create : mytest/views
   create : mytest/views/index.jade
   create : mytest/views/layout.jade
   create : mytest/views/error.jade
   create : mytest/bin
   create : mytest/bin/www

   install dependencies:
     $ cd mytest && npm install

   run the app:
     $ DEBUG=mytest:* npm start

dev-server15:/var/www# cd mytest/
dev-server15:/var/www/mytest# npm install
```

The npm install command completes without any errors.
I start the application by doing the following:

```
dev-server15:/var/www/mytest# DEBUG=mytest:* npm start

> mytest@0.0.0 start /var/www/mytest
> node ./bin/www

  mytest Listening on port 3000 +0ms
```

Then i try to navigate to the index page by going to http://mydevserver15/test

I can see the requests being made in the console... but it returns a 404.

```
dev-server15:/var/www/mytest# DEBUG=mytest:* npm start

> mytest@0.0.0 start /var/www/mytest
> node ./bin/www

  mytest Listening on port 3000 +0ms
GET /mytest 404 734.109 ms - 965
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 12.556 ms - 111
```

I thought out of the box, the default routes worked.

**What I've checked:**

I know that I need references to my routes in the app.js file. 
So I've tried to check and I do see that I have the following entries:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

and then later on, I see:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Here's what i have in package.json so you can see the version numbers:

```
dev-server15:/var/www/mytest# cat package.json 
 {
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Here's the contents of routes/index.js:

```
dev-server15:/var/www/mytest# cat routes/index.js 
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried navigating to the users route.  I've copied and pasted the url for you here, as well as the output on the console:

```
http://mydevserver15:3000/mytest/users
```

This creates the following output in the console:

```
GET /mytest/users 404 74.173 ms - 965
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.851 ms - -
```

Comment: 1. GET /mytest - you requested http://mydevserver15/mytest not /test. 2. /test is not an index page. 3. Show your ./routes/index.js file content.

Comment: @NazarSakharenko sorry, that was a typo on my part.  I did trigger the mytest app.  Please see EDIT 1 for contents of index.js per your request.

Comment: You have one route -> **/** this mean that you should navigate to http://mydevserver15 to see page, if you want page **/test**, you should change **router.get('/'** to **router.get('/test'** or add new one.

Comment: bingo @NazarSakharenko.  That's all it was.  I shouldn't have embedded the application folder name in the URL.  ugh.  can you post as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: As was mentioned pay attention to the correct port.

Comment: yeah, it's not the port but the path I was trying to navigate to.  see previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one route: "**/**", this mean that you should navigate to mydevserver15 to see root page. If you want page **/test**, you should change:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

to

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Or register it as new route.